# Sending files to Kloudless saver from clientside

Tags: kloudless

I'm currently using a dropbox client js script to push zip files to a folder (in test, a couple of k, in production, a couple of hundred meg) - there currently isn't a server/back end, so am posting from an arraybuffer, not a server url.

```
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file("test.txt", "Hello World\n");
    var content = zip.generate({type:"arraybuffer"});
    // ... code to pick a dropbox folder ...//
    client.writeFile(url+"/"+fileName, content, function(error){ ... etc
```

This all works fine - client is able to write the binary file (which Dropbox's own [Saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver) is unfortunately unable to do). I'm trying to see if Kloudless is able to perform the same, since I also need to support google, box, etc at some point. https://github.com/kloudless/file-explorer/'s documentation about its saver says the files are an array of urls ..

```
explorer({
...
files: [{
  "url": "http://<your image url>",
  "name": "filename.extension"
},
```

It doesn't seem to like local storage file references using `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`, so I'm guessing the api is telling the remote services to pull the files rather than pushing their data.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the Kloudless API backend servers stream the file from the URL to the final destination in whichever cloud service you would like the file to be uploaded to (e.g. a folder in a Dropbox account).

If the files are present only on the client-side, I would recommend using the [Kloudless Chooser](http://github.com/kloudless/file-explorer) to instead prompt the user to choose a folder to save the files in, and then handle uploading the file data to that destination via the client-side manually.

To do this, refer to this example configuration: https://jsfiddle.net/PB565/139/embedded/

I have set `retrieve_tokens` to `true` so that my client-side JavaScript will receive not just the metadata of the folder the user chooses to upload the data to but also the Bearer token to use to gain access to the user's account. This allows the client-side JavaScript to then make [upload](https://developers.kloudless.com/docs/latest#files-upload-a-file) or [multipart upload](https://developers.kloudless.com/docs/latest#multipart-upload) requests to Kloudless to upload the file data to that folder. The advantage of multipart uploads is that an error uploading one chunk wouldn't require the whole upload to be retried.

Be sure to add the domain you are hosting the File Explorer on to your Kloudless App's Trusted Domains (on the [App Details page](https://developers.kloudless.com/applications/*/details#trusted-domains)) so that it can in fact receive the Bearer token in the response JS callback. In my JSFiddle example, I would have to add 'fiddle.jshell.net' to my app's list of Trusted Domains to be able to receive the Bearer token to perform further requests from the client side to the Kloudless API.